# How can I create a Macro in excel that will always create a pivot table using raw data?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-pivot, vba

I am trying to automate some pieces of my reports for work. I want to have a macro that will take all the raw data in a worksheet and create/design the same pivot table every time.

I have been able to create a normal table in this way by avoiding absolutes such as Ctrl+shft+ down arrow to select all the data but with Pivot Tables I run into this error:

[image]

Just to be as specific as possible. With my macro use I have been unable to:

1. Create a Pivot Table
2. Rename a worksheet
3. Sort the values from largest to smallest.

In all my macros, these 3 things will cause it to crash in a run time error.

Is there anyway to modify the code to allow these three things to work?

Here is my Macro code. The three things I want to accomplish are in this pivot table macro. Sorry for any miss clicks in the creation of the macro. Thanks for any help you guys might provide.

```
    Sub Create_pivotTable()
'
' Create_pivotTable Macro
'

'
    Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotCache. _
        createPivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Sheets(5)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Debit Party Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Credit Party Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Original Amount"), "Count of Original Amount", _
        xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Transaction Date"), "Count of Transaction Date", _
        xlCount
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Piv Tab"
    Rows("1:2").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CompactLayoutRowHeader = _
        "ORIGINATORS | BENEFICIARY'S"
    Range("B1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "Count of Original Amount")
        .Caption = "Amount"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Count of Transaction Date") _
        .Caption = "Count"
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Amount")
        .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End With
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Debit Party Name"). _
        AutoSort xlDescending, "Amount", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Credit Party Name"). _
        AutoSort xlDescending, "Amount", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 45.86
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Analysis"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium3"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Columns("C:C").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("D7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: at what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: The only thing the macro completes when I run the macro is create a new sheet. the sheet is blank. so line 4?